# Does PostGIS automatically convert upon inserting WKT?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, wkt

I'm quite new to PostGIS so bear with me.

Suppose I have a table defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE gtest (name varchar, geom geometry);
```

At first, to insert, I was doing something like:

```
INSERT INTO gtest
VALUES (
    'Polygon',
    ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))',4326)
);
```

I then discovered that it still works by only doing this:

```
INSERT INTO gtest
VALUES (
    'Polygon',
    'SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'
);
```

When I do a query without converting the geom values back into WKT, they are both encoded properly. Same if I convert the column to EWKT, everything displays properly.

Is there a conversion going on behind the scenes? And if I insert without calling `ST_GeomFromText()`, will all other functions using the column work fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several automatic cast to and from the `geometry` type.

You can type `\dC` in PostgreSQL and you will see all available casts, including:

```
                                     List of casts
     Source type         |         Target type         |      Function      |   Implicit?
-------------------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+---------------
text                     | geometry                    | geometry           | yes
```

This information is also available in the [doc](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry.html) or in this [tutorial](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/geometries.html#casting-from-text).

Since the cast in implicit, it means you don't have to specify it to use it. Note that you can "force" it using `::geometry`:

```
select st_asText('SRID=4326;POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))'::geometry);
           st_astext
--------------------------------
 POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))
(1 row)
```

Regarding the column usability, the column is of type `geometry` so anything that is in this column is a `geometry` and can be used by any function requiring a `geometry`. How the data got there (automatic cast, conversion, extraction from another geometry etc) is not relevant anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer. Do you know if it's possible to forse the cast in the other direction? So by doing `SELECT geom FROM gtest;` the results will automatically be in the text form `POLYGON((0 0,1 0,1 1,0 1,0 0))`?

Comment: @robbieperry22 no, it would return the WKB as text. You can however have a view that contains a column `st_asText(geom)`

Comment: I was wondering however if I could set an implicit cast when converting from geometry. I tried doing `CREATE CAST (geometry AS text) WITH FUNCTION st_astext(geometry) AS IMPLICIT;` but it wouldn't allow it, as there already exists a cast like that, but instead using the `text` function. I can't drop it either because postgis requires it. Any workarounds you can think of that don't involve having a view?

Comment: most of the time one can just use the geometry, so for the few times a printout is required, I would personally use `st_asText(geom)` and wouldn't bother with implicit casts